# Debug freezing machine

Tags: debian, freeze

My machine sometimes freezes seemingly randomly. Looking at the `kern.log`, I can see a strange logging of the 0 character around the time of the freeze:
[image: kern.log log before]
[image: kern.log log after]

How can I further diagnose this problem?

Note: I've anonymized the wlan0 Mac addresses to 00s.

I am on Debian jessie

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.8 (jessie)
Release:    8.8
Codename:   jessie
```

Comment: I'd start by running a memtest session.

Comment: Those 0 characters are probably a by-product of your machine freezing during appending to `kern.log`, not real logged data. In other words, the result of metadata journalling in the filesystem code. The panic log probably appears on the system console, but can't make it into the log file. Unless the console stays in graphical mode, making it impossible to read. Configuring a serial console would be best, but laptops seldom have serial ports nowadays. Network console may or may not work, depending on the nature of the crash.